# How do we rank dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have sample dataframe as below :

**i/p**

```
accountNumber   assetValue  
A100            1000         
A100            500          
B100            600          
B100            200
```

**o/p**

```
AccountNumber   assetValue  Rank
A100            1000         1
A100            500          2
B100            600          1
B100            200          2
```

Now my question is how do we add this rank column on dataframe which is sorted by account number. I am not expecting huge volume of rows so open to idea if I need to do it outside of dataframe.

I am using Spark version 1.5 and SQLContext hence cannot use Windows function

Answer (score 10):

You can use `row_number` function and `Window` expression with which you can specify the `partition` and `order` columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number

val df = Seq(("A100", 1000), ("A100", 500), ("B100", 600), ("B100", 200)).toDF("accountNumber", "assetValue")

df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"accountNumber").orderBy($"assetValue".desc))).show

+-------------+----------+----+
|accountNumber|assetValue|rank|
+-------------+----------+----+
|         A100|      1000|   1|
|         A100|       500|   2|
|         B100|       600|   1|
|         B100|       200|   2|
+-------------+----------+----+
```

Comment: Throws an unsupportedOperationException error when working with Window expresssion partitioned by multiple columns.

Comment: `val df = Seq(("A100", 1000), ("A100", 500), ("B100", 600), ("B100", 200)).toDF("accountNumber", "assetValue")`
`val x = Window.partitionBy('accountNumber).orderBy('assetValue)
df.withColumn("row_number", row_number() over x).show`

Answer (score 8):

**Raw SQL:**

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A100", 1000), ("A100", 500), ("B100", 600), ("B100", 200)
)).toDF("accountNumber", "assetValue")

df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT accountNumber,assetValue, RANK() OVER (partition by accountNumber ORDER BY assetValue desc) AS rank FROM df").show


+-------------+----------+----+
|accountNumber|assetValue|rank|
+-------------+----------+----+
|         A100|      1000|   1|
|         A100|       500|   2|
|         B100|       600|   1|
|         B100|       200|   2|
+-------------+----------+----+
```

Comment: This needs hive context. Looking for solution only with sqlContext