# How to get a new dataframe which only 10 lines per user_id(column name)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
 scala> df.show()
 +-------+-------+                                                               
 |user_id|book_id|
 +-------+-------+
 | 235610|2757548|
 | 235610|2352922|
 | 235610| 620968|
 | 235610|1037143|
 | 235610|2319578|
 |   ... | ....  |
 | 235610|1037143|
 | 235610|2319578|
```

and it`s have three different users in the "user_id" column as follows :

```
scala> val df1 = df.select("user_id").distinct()
scala> df1.show()
+-------+                                                                       
|user_id|
+-------+
| 235610|
| 211065|
| 211050|
+-------+
```

Number of lines per `user("235610","211065","21050")` as follows:

```
scala> df.filter($"user_id"==="235610").count()
res28: Long = 140  

scala> df.filter($"user_id"==="211065").count()
res29: Long = 51

scala> df.filter($"user_id"==="211050").count()
res30: Long = 64
```

Now my problem is how to get a new dataframe which only 10 lines per user_id? Because every `user_id("235610","211065","21050")` is over 10 records per user.

Spark version 2.3.0. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spark version is 1.4, the rank works with hive context.

so register your df on hiveContext:

```
 df.registerTempTable("tempDF")

 val dfRanked = hiveContext.sql("select dataWithRank.*,  
        dense_rank() OVER 
              ( PARTITION BY dataWithRank.book_id ORDER BY dataWithRank.book_id DESC) AS Rank 
   from tempDF as dataWithRank)
dfRanked.filter("Rank>10")
```

here documentation about hive rank:
http://www.openkb.info/2016/02/difference-between-spark-hivecontext.html

Comment: sorry ,my spark verison is 2.3.0.I don't know why the stack overflow shows  my spark version 1.4. and if my spark verison is 2.3.0,Is there a more efficient solution?thank you

Comment: it does't matter the version this is best way. However you can write in the form as say Psidom in the link below:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966590/scala-spark-how-do-we-rank-dataframe-with-sqlcontext-and-version-1-5/42972123

Answer (score 0):

You can try using rank function over partition by user_id and order by book_id.

Based on rank you can filter where rank >=10 to get 10 records per user_id.

I hope it helps.